# How to use OMP in for loops (C Programming)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

What am I doing wrong below? The code pegs CPU at 100% and does not end. Seems to be an infinite loop. Help appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  
  unsigned long number2;
  unsigned long number = 1;
   
  #pragma omp parallel for  
  for (number = 1; number <= 10000; number++)
  {
    unsigned long max = 0, count = 0;    
    number2 = number;

    while (number2 != 1)
    {
      if (number2 > max)
        max = number2;
      if (number2 % 2 == 0)
        number2 /= 2;
      else
        number2 = 3 * number2 + 1;
      count++;
    }    
  }

}
```

Update: The following works.

Not sure what the root cause was. It could've been

1. data type was overflowing its boundaries, i.e. int -> unsigned int
2. number2 had to be made private, etc.

````
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  unsigned int i;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
  {
    unsigned int number2 = i; unsigned int max; unsigned int count = 0;
    while (number2 != 1)
    {
      if (number2 > max)
        max = number2;
      if (number2 % 2 == 0)
        number2 /= 2;
      else
        number2 = 3 * number2 + 1;
      count++;
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Is `number2` shared or private?

Comment: @Shawn `number2` is private. I've resolved the issue. Will update OP. Thank you!

Comment: In your second version, `max` is not initialized when it looks like you want `unsigned int max = i;`

Answer (score 2):

In the first version of your code `number2` is shared, all threads access/modify it simultaneously. It is a data race ---> undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

Not sure what the root cause was. It could've been

data type was overflowing its boundaries, i.e. int -> unsigned int

or
number2 had to be made private, etc.